# mysql runtime information gadget or plugin

Tags: mysql, wamp

My questions says it all,Is there nay plugin that would show all the process and connections made to mySQL DB. `(wamp)` similar to softwares that shows memory consumption,usage etc.
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Why have you tagged it with sql-server and oracle?

Comment: @MihailGolubev  asically i tagged people who uses databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this query

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

Comment: i used this command but this is not as much handy as a GUI based plugin

Comment: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/mysql/how-show-open-database-connections-mysql